# Do medical staff report wounds from rubber bullets like they do for gunshot wounds?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, medical

This question comes from a curious debate I'm in the middle of. Thankfully it's a completely wound-free debate (physically speaking). But I'm not certain if a rubber bullet wound is 'real' gunshot wound legally speaking. Have there even been court cases or public policy referencing it?

Comment: Under what circumstances would it matter, legally speaking?  Most laws that pertain to injuries would distinguish them by severity and not by cause.  Of course there might be standard procedures in the medical community around classifying and reporting injuries, but that would not be a matter for Law.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that "medical staff reporting" is a matter of law, or even regulated by any government entity?

Answer (score -2):

There's no statute that I'm aware of that would require it.  First, it's a bit of a slippery slope once you start reporting things that hit you and hurt. Who is to say what actually caused the impact?  As far as I know, your GF hits you with a pointy end of a broom, it's gonna look a lot like a rubber bullet hit.

A bullet hole leaves very specific wound and it is testable.  Often times there's even a little metallic piece that confirms the shot.